# Python - List is not defined

Tags: python-3.x

```
from typing import List, Tuple, Dict, TextIO
def names(file:TextIO) -> None:
    """ create a list with all the names from the file
    """
    lines = ""
    firstname = ""
    lastname = ""
    name_list = []
    file = open(file, 'r')
    for line in file:
      line = line.strip()
      lines += line
    for i in range(len(lines)):
      if lines[i] == ",":
        lastname += lines[i+2]
        first = i
        last = i + 3
      while lines[first].islower() and lines[last].islower():
        firstname += lines[first]
        lastname += lines[last]
        first -= 1
        last += 1
    name_list.append(firstname + " " + lastname)
```

keep returning the name_list is not defined, where went wrong?

Comment: Can you fix indentation error before? (line 15)

Comment: Sorry. Just fixed

Comment: I guess you are calling this function from some code, like print(names('yourfile.path.txt')), but names is not returning anything. I think you have to add one more line return name_list. But I am just guessing, it would be easier if you add full code, or at least explain what you are expecting the function to do

Comment: Can you include the full stack trace? There are a couple of problems with your function and your error message doesn't seem to fit them.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and I didn't get the same error. Maybe check the indentation is correct in your code?

On the other hand you have a problem here:

```
  if lines[i] == ",":
    lastname += lines[i+2]
    first = i
    last = i + 3
```

You're declaring local variables in an `if` block, they will not be visible later in the code, such as in the `while` loop just afterwards.

You need to declare the variables in a block where they will be visible by all the subsequent blocks that use them.

My suggestion would be to add them to the variables at the top of your function:

```
lines = ""
firstname = ""
lastname = ""
name_list = []
lines = 0 # or whatever value it's supposed to start with
last = 0  # or whatever value it's supposed to start with
```

Comment: Just tried on local shell since I was doing it online, but still the same thing. I just don't get why it says undefined while I clearly defined it in advance

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/TealEuphoricYellowwhitebutterfly I tried online too, still don't get your error...